# Overriding a python module

Tags: python, overriding, python-module

Is it possible to override a module with a class ?

Let me explain,

Here is the filesystem

```
foo
|-- bar
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- config.py
|-- __init__.py
```

Is it possible to override `config.py` from `foo.bar.__init__.py` so that whenever someone imports `foo.bar.config` they are importing overriden `config` instead of the version from `config.py` ?

If yes how do I do it ?

Ps: I will be overriding config.py based on certain conditions.

Comment: If you can modify `foo/bar/__init__.py`, why can't you simply update `foo/bar/config.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define a class in `foo/bar/__init__.py` with the name `config` and that will be imported. But why don't you just change the `config.py`?

```
In [4]: !ls foo
__init__.py   bar/
In [5]: !ls foo/bar
__init__.py   config.py
In [6]: !cat foo/bar/__init__.py
class config(object):
    pass
In [7]: from foo.bar import config    
In [8]: type(config)
Out[8]: type

$ echo "" > foo/bar/__init__.py
$ ipython

In [1]: from foo.bar import config    
In [2]: type(config)
Out[2]: module
```